# Recover Permanently Deleted Folder (SHIFT+DELETE) Windows 10 Bootcamp SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, file-recovery, recovery

Accidentally permanently deleted a folder (w/ SHIFT+DELETE) on a [Windows 10 Bootcamp SSD](https://9to5mac.com/2017/08/31/how-windows-10-mac-boot-camp-external-drive-video/): is there any way to recover it? None of the major recovery sofware sees it (e.g. Recuva, EaseUS, DiskDrill, MiniTool. No History or Backups was enabled. Many thanks

Comment: The majority of file recover software alll work the exactly the same.  There are a few differences, and they are solutions that are better than others, but if not a single peice of software discovers the deleted files then **the files are simply gone.**  You will have to restore those files from a backup

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution was right there. The only thing that actually worked: ShadowExplorer (https://www.shadowexplorer.com/downloads.html). Opened, selected a Shadow Copy and was able to take a copy of a backup successfully!

Comment: Although most pdfs and images are corrupted...